# Understanding Sangria-graphql Executor

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

Currently, I'm learning Sangria-graphql with playframework and going through tutorial from [here](http://sangria-graphql.org/getting-started/). I understand the Executor `Executor.execute(schema, query, new ProductRepo)` which takes schema, query and context. On the other hand, as I go through demo example code, I came with following use of Executor where operationName and Variables are also provided. For instance,

```
Executor.execute(SchemaDefinition.StarWarsSchema, queryAst, new CharacterRepo,
            operationName = operation,
            variables = variables getOrElse Json.obj(),
            deferredResolver = DeferredResolver.fetchers(SchemaDefinition.characters),
            maxQueryDepth = Some(10))
          .map(Ok(_))
```

I'm not quite getting it. If the variable means arguement for our query then query it self contain query params, such as `id` in following query.

```
{
  human(id: "1000") {
    name
    height(unit: FOOT)
  }
}
```

Also, why and how the operationName is beneficial in this context? So, can anyone explain me about it along with how client provide query request for these operationName and variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables, in this case, means something different than parameters (like your `id: "1000"`).

Have a look at the [documentation of variables in GraphQL](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables).

Same goes for the `operationName`: [documentation for this](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#operation-name)